# Transaction take too long

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I did a transaction 4days ago with low fee that was about 0.2 USD and it has been not confirmed yet. 
I just wanna know how i can cancel it ? 
Or how many days it takes to this transaction to be confirmed. 
Would you please help me through

Comment: You can't cancel it and it will probably never confirm. It's probably best just to wait a few days and make a replacement transaction with a higher fee.

Answer (score 0):

visit
https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/blocks

since transaction fees went up to $35   Fee/kB (USD)

or open
https://blockchair.com/

Answer (score 0):

Since your transaction fee is not that high you will experience longer transaction confirmation due to bitcoin network is congested. To track how many confirmations need to confirm your transfer you can check it here:

https://blockchain.info/

just provide a transaction hash and you will the whole process there and more useful information.

Comment: entering the tx hash on blockchain.info just provides details on the tx, and if it is unconfirmed, it will show this. That doesn't help the OP - it's basically what he already explained in his post. The other three comments help way better for his purposes. This page gives an indication, how long it would take: https://bitcoinfees.earn.com

Comment: Usually after TX there is blockchain info that you can use to track on how many confirmation you should complete.